# Current user with ASP.NET Forms authentication app

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-7, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to retrieve the current user in my web application that uses ASP.NET Forms authentication.
However, `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns domain\windowsUser, NOT the username that was used in the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method.
I am using Forms authentication in my config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Views/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="1" cookieless="UseUri">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

I am also trying to follow Microsoft's walk through and retrieve the Authentication ticket using the following snippet:

```
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         var ident = User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
        if (ident != null)
        {

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ident.Ticket;
            var name = ticket.Name;
        }
    }
```

However, ident is always null because it's WindowsIdentity not FormsIdentity. What's wrong here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `User.Identity.Name` to get the user name.

Windows authentication does not use the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

Comment: User.Identity.Name also returns the same domain\windowsUser NOT the ASP.NET user. User.Identity is of Type WIndowsIdentity and the AuthenticationType is set to "Negotiate".

Comment: what authentication system are you using in your web.config? forms or windows?

Comment: Forms. Here is a snippet:     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Views/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="1" cookieless="UseUri">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

Comment: and how are you authenticating people?

Comment: Using my own code to check password. If the check is successful, I call this: FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, rememberUser.Checked);